# Is my (repeated-measures) multilevel model correctly specified in R?

Tags: r, modeling, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

**Objective:** I would like to make sure I specified my multilevel model correctly in `R` using `nlme` package.

**Background:** I have a rather simple *within-subject* (repeated-measures) design where participants answered an emotion questionnaire twice in *two counter-balanced conditions*: condition 1 and condition 2 (i.e., participants either did condition 1 first, or condition 2 first, but always did both). We're interested in predicting *emotion* (measured **twice**, i.e., the questionnaire completed after each condition) by *personality* (measured **once**, before the experiment began, i.e., a baseline measure) and to verify whether that relationship differs based on condition (and if there's an interaction). If I understand correctly, condition is crossed with subject.

**Sample Data:**

```
ID|condition|personality|emotion
1      1         2.5       5.0
1      2         2.5       4.9
2      1         4.0       2.6
2      2         4.0       2.3
3      1         3.3       4.3
3      2         3.3       2.9
4      1         4.2       1.0
4      2         4.2       1.0
```

I have taken a class on multilevel models, read many PDFs, did tutorials, and watched videos on YouTube. However, I'm still new to multilevel modelling and I cannot find an example identical to my situation to make sure I'm not doing an obvious mistake so I would just like someone to confirm I am doing this correctly. For the reference, here are a few other relevant forum posts I have consulted and that may be of some help: [link1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235201/specifying-multilevel-model-with-time-series-covariance-in-nlme), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682175/how-to-code-a-nested-repeated-measures-model-in-r), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120251/specification-of-a-multilevel-model-in-package-lme4-in-r), [link4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376983/have-i-correctly-specified-my-lmer-model-for-crossed-nested-experiment), [link5](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111907/specifying-variable-levels-in-multilevel-repeated-measures-in-r-using-lme4), [link6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996201/how-can-i-include-repeated-measures-to-my-lmer-correctly), and [link7](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58745/using-lmer-for-repeated-measures-linear-mixed-effect-model). I'm getting confused because many of these examples are much more complicated than my own situation.

**My Tentative Model Specification:**

```
lme(emotion ~ 1 + personality*condition, random=(~1|ID), data=mydata, method="ML")
```

**Question:** Is my model correctly specified given my design?

Comment: It looks reasonable, at least given the description and without having access to the study protocol and to the data. Maybe it could be worth taking as fixed effect also a time dummy (first observation or second one) to see if there is a time trend.

Comment: @MichaelM Thanks! I'm not sure if my condition would be random or fixed slope/intercept. I would think condition is fixed because it is "fixed" (determined) by the experimenter; on the other hand, I would expect the slope of my outcome measure to vary based on the condition, so I thought in this case I needed to let it vary freely (i.e., be "random") because I don't want to force the two conditions to have the same slopes. Can you give simple experimental examples of fixed and random crossed effects? Also, would my model have random or fixed intercepts? Should I specify any of these somewhere?

Comment: (And regarding the time dummy, my colleague has confirmed there's no time effect/trend earlier so we removed it from the model.)